# Injection from $\prod_{i=1}^n\{1,...,m\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, but with a constraint

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm looking for a injection from $\prod_{i=1}^n\{1,...,m\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

I thought of $f(i_1,...,i_n)=p_1^{i_1} \cdots p_n^{i_n}$ , where $p_j$ is the $j$-th prime number.

However, this injection has a downside which is that the size of the numbers increase exponentially... I would like the injection to have smallest largest number. In the above example, the largest number would be $p_1^{m} \cdots p_n^{m}$

Comment: Is this not quite straightforward? Simply inject the (finite) set on the left to the first $m^n$ natural numbers?

Comment: @AlephNull I was looking for an explicit expression for that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the base-$m$ expansion of integers. The map is given as follows:
$$
f(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n) = (i_1 - 1)m^{n-1} + (i_2 - 1)m^{n-2} + \cdots + (i_{n-1} - 1)m + (i_n-1) + 1
$$
(This would look a lot better if you let $0$ be a natural number and use $\{0, \ldots, m-1\}$ instead, because then we wouldn't need all the $1$'s in there. But you do you.)

For instance, for $m = 10, n = 3$, we have
$$
f(2, 3, 4) = (2-1)\cdot 100 + (3-1)\cdot 10 + (4-1) + 1 = 124
$$
(If we had used $0$ to $m-1$ instead, it would've been $f(2, 3, 4) = 234$, which is clearly much nicer.)

Comment: Arthur, if $m$ were to vary in such a way that, with each $i_j$ we had $m_j$. Then would we have $(i_j-1)m_j$? I think so, but would just like to confirm. ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. No. In that case, instead of $(i_{k} - 1)m^{n-k}$, we would have $(i_{k} - 1)m_{k+1}\cdot m_{k+2}\cdots m_n$.

Comment: Ups... Yes. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. One example would be the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system), where $m_k = n-k + 1$.